# Push notification filter duplicates

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic2

i am using ionic2 with cordova native firebase plugin.

when i want to inform my user with a push notification that a new message is in the chat.
so i create a notification everytime a user is posting a message and send it to my topic: /topics/chat

i was hoping that there is a logic on the device that checks if a notification is the same as before and filters the new out.

but now i get a notification on every single line a user is adding a message, which is not so funny ;-)

is there a simple way to realize this, without gathering all usertokens and inform them one by one, and check before if they already got a chat notification?

EDIT:
chat.service.ts

```
//Angular
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
//Services
import { LoginService } from '../services/login.service';
import { FCMPushService } from '../services/fcmpush.service';
//Models
import { ChatModel } from '../models/chat';

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {

    constructor (
        private loginService: LoginService,
        private fcmpushService: FCMPushService
    ){ }

    create(object: ChatModel): void {
        this.loginService.getUser().subscribe( userdata => {
            object.user = this.loginService.getAuth().uid;
            object.created = new Date().getTime();
            this.loginService.af.database.list(`/games/${userdata.gameid}/chat/`).push(object).then( data => {
                this.fcmpushService.sendNotification('Chat', 'There is a new message in your aTippr chat!', '/topics/chat');
            });
        })
    }
}
```

fcmpush.service.ts

```
//Angular
import { Injectable, Inject }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
//Ionic
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
//Rxjs
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class FCMPushService {

    constructor (
        public platform: Platform,
        public http: Http,
        private FireNative: Firebase,
    ){}

    sendNotification(title: String, content: String, to: String): Observable<any> {
        //Headers
        let headers = new Headers({"Authorization": 'key=####'});
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        //Body
        let body = {
            "notification":{
                "title":title,
                "body":content,
                "sound":"default",
                "icon":"ic_notification"
            },
            /*"data":{
                "param1":"value1",
                "param2":"value2"
            },*/
            "to":to,
            "priority":"high",
            "restricted_package_name":"###"
        }
        // Send
        return this.http.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', body, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is broad.. what logic are you using to receive and store notification..you need to provide some code

Comment: i am not sure how it can help, but well i added my 2 services that triggers and send the notification ;-)

Comment: Usually you write the actual message in the notification and not "new message received!". So best advice I can give is unregister from notifications and then register again after viewing message

Comment: thanks for your answer, but is it possible to unregister in background mode?